# Why is my PHP script (MySQL Query) so slow?

Tags: php, mysql

I ran a script I made a couple of minutes ago and it still hasn't finished running.

**Now it has,** I got a 500 Internal Server Error.

EDIT--- The error is occuring on line 126 which is port of the while loop here:

```
while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
}
```

Please can you tell me what is causing my script to be so slow?

```
if ($param == "closeAccount") {
    $username = NULL;
    $password = NULL;
    $emailAdd = NULL;
    $id = NULL;
    if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        $username = $_GET['username'];
    }
    else {
        exit("No username is set");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['password'])) {
        $password = md5($_GET['password']);
    }
    else {
        exit("No password is set");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['emailAddress'])) {
        $emailAdd = $_GET['emailAddress'];
    }
    else {
        exit("No email address is set");
    }
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
        exit("Account doesn't exist");
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
    $query = NULL;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $query = NULL;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    }
    $query = NULL;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
    }
    $query = NULL;
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
    exit("Closed");
}
```

Comment: you should avoid sql in while loops...actually in most loops

Comment: you don't need single quotes around your table names in your queries, and yes, try to avoid queries in loops

Comment: -1 For posting SQL-injectable code.

Comment: @Johan, whats the point?

Comment: @Harigntka, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: @Johan I am talking about the -1, what was the point in that?

Comment: The point is that your code is full of security holes: SQL-injection, hash with no salt. That's bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have a lot of redundancy. I dont have your direct database, so I could be slightly off on how you have your structure, but you may benefit from skipping the SELECT statements in the lower half.

Example:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` 
    WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' 
    AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {
    exit("Account doesn't exist or wrong password entered");
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$id = $row["id"]

$query = NULL;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Accounts` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and it does it almost immediately, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Harigntka: It'll work even better if you add foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: @a1ex07, what is a foreign key?

Comment: Foreign key is a way of creating relations between two tables. An entry (key) in table 1 points to an entry in table 2. Any change in table 2 is immediately reflected on table 1 without the need for the programmer to interfere.

Comment: How could I set this up, it sounds like a much more efficient way of programming

Comment: It's a constraint used to enforce referential integrity in database. Take a look on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html . In mysql it works for INNODB engine only.

Answer (score 2):

500 Internal Server Error should result in details logged in your web server error log on your server.  Take a look in your web server's error log and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
```

Is likely to be failing.

Change them all to this

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Edit :: Oh yea, there's a HUGE sql injection problem here. remember to do

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usernmame']);
```

Unless you want injection to happen!

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to do a while here if you are suppose to get only one user. Just remove the while loop.

  ```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
  [...]
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $id = $row["id"];
  }
  ```
- Setting the $query variable to NULL is useless if you set it on the line after :

  ```
  $query = NULL;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  ```
- Here your `SELECT` queries are not used. They are useless, you can remove them.

  ```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
  }
  $query = NULL;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  }
  $query = NULL;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Posts` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  }
  $query = NULL;
  $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Accounts` WHERE `Username` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password' AND `Email Address` = '$emailAdd'");
  ```
- The while loop is useless in those cases, because you are always executing the SAME query. Replace that :

  ```
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
  }
  ```

  by that :

  ```
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Comments` WHERE `accountID` = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, queries in a loop should be avoided at all cost.

Take that line you pointed out and do something like this below:

```
$ids_to_delete = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       $ids_to_delete[] = (int)  $row['id'];   
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `Likes` WHERE `accountID` IN(" . implode(',', $ids_to_delete) . ")");
```